# Solving differential equation with x' squared/ absolute value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to analyse the movement of a system in which a weight is connected to a spring, which oscillates in wind, with the wind inflicting drag force on the weight, proportional to the speed of wind relative to the speed of the weight squared.

When the forces are added, we get the equation below, where: x(t) is the position and the following constants are all positive: A - weight mass, B - constant for the square drag law, C- wind speed, D- spring coefficient.
I do not know how to solve the following equation, even with expanding into series or similar tricks, but if you know them please use them.  $$A \ddot x - B (C-\dot x )^2 + D x = 0$$
The real equation looks like this $$A \ddot x - B (C-\dot x ) \lvert C-\dot x \rvert + D x = 0$$ with the +/- of the parenthesis being important - if we get the correct correct sign, the forces are properly added - the force of wind changes direction when the weight gets faster/slower, otherwise we get the result only if the speed of wind is always faster than the weight.
If it is of any help, the ending position of the weight is $x = \frac BDC^2$.
As mentioned, any tricks that lead even to an approximated result are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

You get such combinations of derivatives and squares from the second derivative of the exponential of a function. So here you would try
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\exp(k(Ct-x))=k\exp(k(Ct-x))[C-\dot x]\\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\exp(k(Ct-x))=k\exp(k(Ct-x))[-\ddot x+k(C-\dot x)^2]\\
$$
Now select $k$ to match the structure of the leading two terms of the DE.

On the segments where $(C-\dot x)$ has a constant sign, this transforms the equation into a linear one.

Comment: Following your suggestion, one can rewrite the first equation as $$\ddot{u}+\lambda xu=0, \tag{1}$$where $u=\exp(k(Ct-x))$ and $\lambda$ is some constant, but $(1)$ is not a linear equation --- or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right. My trick works well for the free fall equations, but not for the spring case. Still, the transformed equation is in the separable Hamilton form. This gives an energy functional. Not a complete solution, but more information.

Comment: I've updated the problem, I explained the background a bit better. I unfortunately do have oscillations that (I at least) can't solve using this trick. I can solve it numerically of course but the goal is to solve it analytically as best as possible. I used the absolute value because it simplified the process of thinking about the forces, I couldn't figure out if there is any way to maybe exploit imaginary numbers to make the jumps of force direction possible. Any further input would be appreciated.